# Proving that the union of all line segments connecting two points of a closed subset of the unit circle is compact

Tags: real-analysis

Note: The unit circle $\mathbb{T} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x|| = 1\}$

Let $A$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{T}$ containing more than one point, and let $E$ be the union of all line segments connecting two points of $A$. Let's prove that $E$ is compact.

I recently proved (in the previous problem in this homework set) that a connected metric space that contains more than 1 point is uncountable. I am not sure if that will come in handy with this proof, but it does seem that from that result we have that $A$ is uncountable. But that seems to be redundant, since $A$ being closed implies uncountability doesn't it? Well, I guess we don't know that A is connected. Is $E$ connected? If so, how do I show that? I am thinking that since $E$ is a union of connected sets it must be connected, though I am not entirely sure I can claim that.

I am trying to reason out how I can show that $E$ is sequentially compact, that seems to be the most intuitive way to prove this.

Comment: About your comments: $A$ can be both countable or uncountable, eg. $A=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and $A=\mathbb{T}$. $E$ will be connected, but it's not beacause it is a union of conected sets, since, for example, $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ is not connected.

Comment: I'm guessing you *actually* mean $\;E\;$ is the union of all line segments **within** $\;\Bbb T\;$ joining two points of $\;A\; $,  right? Otherwise boundedness is going to be an issue here.

Comment: Yes. Doesn't "line segments of points of A" imply that they are within $\mathbb{T}$ since $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{T}$?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, line segments, not lines

Comment: Yes @HagenvonEitzen, "Segments"...but **where** ? A union of segments can easily be unbounded.

Comment: No @JohanLiebert, it doesn't.

Comment: @DonAntonio Well, this is how my professor wrote up the question. I reckon he's pretty smart.

Comment: I think I see it now, @JohanLiebert: the segment's extreme points are points in $\;A\;$ . Fine. Thanks.

Comment: Also Aristotle was pretty smart and in practically all the scientific stuff he dealt with he was dead wrong.

Comment: @DonAntonio It was a joke ;-)

Comment: Well, the thing about Aristotle wasn't, unfortunately, as it had a terrible effect on human knowledge for almost 2,000 years. Anyway I got the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sequence compactness: Let $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $E$.
For each $n$, we we find $a_n,b_n\in \mathbb T$ and $t_n\in[0,1]$ such that $e_n$ is on the line segment joining $a_n$ and $b_n$ and more precisely $e_n=ta_n+(1-t)b_n$.
As $\mathbb T$ is compact, by switching to a subsequence if necessary, we may assume that $a_n\to a\in \mathbb T$. and as $A$ is closed we have in fact $a\in A$. By repeating this step we may assume that also $b_n\to b\in A$ and also $t_n\to t$ (as $[0,1]$ is compact as well).
As the map $\mathbb T^2\times[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$, $(a,b,t)\mapsto ta+(1-t)b$ is continuous, $e_n$ converges to $ta+(1-t)b\in E$ .